# localStorage not updating my projectData

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My localStorage.getItem is not updating the data from the DB. but the changes happens only when I re-run the program for the second, it updates the localStorage and displays the modified data.

```
$scope.projectData = $.parseJSON(localStorage.setItem('projectData'));
 (function() {
   console.log('Local Storage Updated')
   return localStorage.getItem('projectdata');
 })();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` is meant to get the localStorage data not to update it. `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value' );` is what you need to update the local storage.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - I have edited the question, I use `setItem`. Kindly have a look now, I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Why are you assigning `localStorage.setItem('projectData')` to `$scope.projectData`?

Comment: `$scope.projectData` will be a global variable.

Comment: @Pradeep check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it

Assuming your projectData is an Object, so you will do this.

```
//localStorage.setItem('key','value');
//localStorage.getItem('key');
//You don't need to json stringify or parse if its just a string value.
localStorage.setItem('projectData', JSON.stringify($scope.projectData));
 (function() {
   console.log('Local Storage Updated')
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('projectdata'));
 })();
```

Assuming your projectData is a String, so you will do this.

```
//localStorage.setItem('key','value');
//localStorage.getItem('key');
//You don't need to json stringify or parse if its just a string value.
localStorage.setItem('projectData', $scope.projectData);
 (function() {
   console.log('Local Storage Updated')
   return localStorage.getItem('projectdata');
 })();
```

Comment: I'm my projectData is an Object, and I'm getting this error: err --- Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Pradeep which error? and if it's an object then use the first example in my answer

Comment: Yes, I have your code. I'm getting a syntax error
`Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: `$scope.projectData` is not a global variable anymore.

Comment: @Pradeep Your data is already an object. No need to parse it. The javascript interpreter has already parsed it for you. So get it without json.parse

Comment: Still, not updating on the first run. The data getting updated with the new values only in the second run.

Comment: You are doing something wrong somewhere. We can't tell unless you show us your complete code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pradeepgokul/o2pcqeqd/ - the complete controller code

Comment: it won't work like this. Reproduce your error in plunker or something. I can't read that long code. I mean't by complete code that HTML + Controller code in a snippet which is giving or producing the same error that you are facing. So we can correct that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 $scope.projectData = {"prodnum": "63",
            "price": "139.00",
            "prodname": "PEANUT BUTTER INDULGENCE MS",
            "quantity": "1.00",
            "tax_amount": "6.95",
            "parent_id": "0"}
     localStorage.setItem('projectData', JSON.stringify($scope.projectData));
```